# Opening another workbook using inputbox. Not letting me include quotation marks

Tags: vba, excel

I want my code to open another workbook by having the user copy and paste the link into an input box. Here is my code:

```
Sub Extraps()

Dim Link As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

With wb1
Link = Application.InputBox("Copy and paste the link")
End With

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Link)
```

This code works fine. However, you have to delete the quotation marks when you copy and paste the link into the inputbox. Is there any way to go about this so the user does not have to delete the quotations?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Replace`:

```
With wb1
Link = Replace(Application.InputBox("Copy and paste the link"), """", "")
End With
```